# Connecting HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I just recently got into HTML/CSS and Javascript. I am making a website for a rock paper scissors game but first wanted to make sure that the code I had written for the game worked (I'm using JSbin to run it for now). The javascript worked fine when I had the input using prompt(). I then looked around to find a way to make it so that people could type their choice into a box and then have that be the input. My current HTML code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html>
<center>
<title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
<p1>Welcome to <em>JavaScript</em> Rock-Paper-Scissors! Please type your choice and press continue</p>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button onclick="game();">Go!</button>
</center>
</html>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var userChoice = input.toLowerCase();
var cpuChoice = Math.random();
if (cpuChoice < 0.34) {
    cpuChoice = "rock";
}
else if (cpuChoice <= 0.67) {
    cpuChoice = "paper";
}
else {
    cpuChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        confirm("It's a tie!");
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock")  {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            confirm("You Win!");
        }
        else {
            confirm("You lost");    
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            confirm("You Win!");
        }
    else {
            confirm("You lost");    
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            confirm("You Win!");
        }
        else {
            confirm("You lost");
        }
    }
    else {
        confirm("I'm sorry, that isn't an option. Please try again");
    }
};
compare(userChoice, cpuChoice);
```

I ran the javascript through JSHint and fixed all the errors that It pointed out, put it back into JSbin but it still didn't work. I'm sure that I'm making a really stupid mistake but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You call a function `game()` with your button but I see no such function defined.

Comment: Your head and body is missing from your html.

Comment: You also need to include the javascript in your page.

Comment: Can you add a link to your JSBin?

Comment: CodeCademy, I've also followed this course! You refer to `game()` in your HTML but in the Javascript there is no function `game()`. I remember that the function `game()` is the function to run the entire javascript code, so add that function at the top of everything and close it at the bottom of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your code works fine assuming your function is named properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/R5GmH/

I've added the following:

```
function game() {
    ....
}
```

Also note that the fiddle is set to load the script in the document head.

P.s. This might work better with a select box: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/R5GmH/4

---

In response to your comment:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-css-file.css"></link>
    <script src="my-js-file.js"></script>
</head>
```

This assumes that all 3 files are in the same directory. Read up on relative URL paths for other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it for when I'm using jsbin. do you know how to run it if I have 3 notepad++ files? one for HTML, one for CSS and one for js?